# How to remove data from the DB when an app is uninstalled from the shopify store

Tags: php, shopify

I am creating a Shopify app using PHP. I want to delete the store info from the database when someone uninstalls the app. I have found this code but I have no idea where to add this and how to trigger it when an app in uninstalled from the store.

```php
$webhook_delete = [
    'webhook' =>
        [
            'topic' => 'app/uninstalled',
            'address' => 'https://icodebreakers.us/shopifyapp/delete_store_info.php?shop=' . $shop_url . '',
            'format' => 'json',
        ],
];
$result = $shopify('POST /admin/webhooks.json', $webhook_delete);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared in a Webhook Subscription creation code. You need to create this webhook subscription in Shopify when the app is installed. Now with this done when your App is uninstalled, you will get a notification in the URL you have mentioned in the address of the webhook subscription. You can validate the request and perform whatever task you want to.

Update: Create uninstall webhook for Shopify

```php
$uninstallWebhook = $shopify('POST /admin/webhooks.json', array(), array
(
    'webhook' => array
    (
        "topic" => "app/uninstalled",
        "address"=> "<URL where you want shopify to notify you about the uninstall>",
        "format"=> "json"
    )
));
```

Comment: Hi, I have created this code in php. And I am using the that url for webhook configuration in my shopify partner apps. But nothing happened. uninstall/app is not triggering. Please see this image https://prnt.sc/oia4pf

Comment: Have you checked if the webhook has been created? The webhook won't trigger if it hasn't been created.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I check that?

Comment: Use fetch webhook api - https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook#index-2019-07

Comment: Then the webhook has not been created. First, create the "uninstall webhook" after the app is installed. Then when you uninstall the app you will be notified in the URL you have provided while creating the webhook. Please note webhooks won't be created with localhost URLs. You need to use tunneling services like ngrok or serveo or pagekite if you are trying it from your local environment.

Comment: I have updated code to create uninstall webhook in shopify

Comment: You mean I need to add this webhook code in oauth.php file?

Comment: And the address "address"=> "<URL where you want shopify to notify you about the uninstall>", I want to remove data from the database for which I have used the address=> https://icodebreakers.us/shopifyapp/delete_store_info.php

Comment: @Neha i would suggest you first read up what is a webhook and how it works - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook. Secondly, please read Shopify Documentation thoroughly. It would be difficult to make you understand solutions if you don't understand what a webhook is.

Answer (score 0):

If your use ngrok I believe it will appear in the console this when your app is uninstalled:

POST /abc/yourfile     200 OK

If you believe that the webhook had been created. In `delete_store_info.php` put these line of code

```
$webhook = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook = json_decode($webhook, TRUE);
$newFileName = "something.txt";
file_put_contents($newFileName, $webhook);
```

It will catch the json shopify send when you uninstall your apps and put into file something.txt after that get the info you use to store in db. Json usually look like

```
{
  "id": 690933842,
  "name": "Super Toys",
  "email": "super@supertoys.com",
  "domain": "super.myshopify.com",
  "province": "Tennessee",
  "country": "US",
  "address1": "190 MacLaren Street",
  "zip": "37178",
  "city": "Houston",
  "source": null,
  "phone": "3213213210",
  "latitude": null,
  "longitude": null,
  "primary_locale": "en",
  "address2": null,
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "currency": "USD",
  "customer_email": "super@supertoys.com",
  "timezone": "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
  "iana_timezone": null,
  "shop_owner": "Steve Jobs",
  "money_format": "$",
  "money_with_currency_format": "$ USD",
  "weight_unit": "kg",
  "province_code": "TN",
  "taxes_included": null,
  "tax_shipping": null,
  "county_taxes": null,
  "plan_display_name": "Shopify Plus",
  "plan_name": "enterprise",
  "has_discounts": true,
  "has_gift_cards": true,
  "myshopify_domain": null,
  "google_apps_domain": null,
  "google_apps_login_enabled": null,
  "money_in_emails_format": "$",
  "money_with_currency_in_emails_format": "$ USD",
  "eligible_for_payments": true,
  "requires_extra_payments_agreement": false,
  "password_enabled": null,
  "has_storefront": true,
  "eligible_for_card_reader_giveaway": false,
  "finances": true,
  "primary_location_id": 905684977,
  "checkout_api_supported": true,
  "multi_location_enabled": false,
  "setup_required": false,
  "force_ssl": false,
  "pre_launch_enabled": false,
  "enabled_presentment_currencies": [
    "USD"
  ]
}
```

The ?shop= is no needed because Shopify send info your need already.

Comment: I am not using ngrok. I am using php to built an app for shopify.

Comment: so just skip that line. ngrok create a tunnel to link your localhost only.